# How to programmatically create and alter table with MyBatis?

Tags: hibernate, mybatis

Currently, I use Hibernate to create a table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private Department department;
}
```

Modifying the `Employee` class will alter the table.

e.g

```
    @Column(name = "new_column")
    private String new_column;
```

How do you do that in MyBatis?

The current solution I use right now is to alter the table from pgAdmin or MySQL Workbench or push a commit to create a method to alter the table.

```
@Mapper
public class Employee {
  @Update("ALTER TABLE ....")
  int alter();
}
```

Comment: MyBatis is not an ORM, but an application layer that automates SQL execution for your application with a lot of bells and whistles. There are ORMs, however, that use MyBatis behind the scenes but I doubt they will take control of your database. Better use DDL to do that safely.

Comment: Lookup the `mybatis-migrate` project.